# null is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State)

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app in react native, everything was working fine, and everytinhg is still working fine on android emulator, but on ios emulator I keep getting this error.

It seems to be linked with stackNavigator but I don't understand why it would suddenly stop working and still working on android.

```
import {
  createStackNavigator, createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

import TabNavigation from './NavigationScreens/TabNavigation';
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginScreen: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions :{ headerLeft: null}
    },
    TabNavigation: {
      screen: TabNavigation,
      navigationOptions :{ headerLeft: null }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'TabNavigation'
  }
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default MyApp;
```

I installed and linked rn-gesture-handler-module as I saw it many times on solutions but it doesn't change anything..  any help ?

Comment: Have you tried running the project from Xcode? That usually shows different errors and can identify a problem

Comment: Have you linked it manually? It seems a linking problem

Answer (score 3):

If you are using cocoapods, try to run:

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Thanks this answer helped me. I was using the react-native version 0.60.

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting `navigationOptions:{headerLeft: null}`,
have you tried setting it up as, since it seems like you don't want the header:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
 LoginScreen : {screen: LoginScreen,},
 TabNavigation :{screen: TabNavigation,},
},{
 initialRouteName: 'TabNavigation',
 headerMode: 'none'}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still experiencing the issue but often cleaning the current build and building again does the trick for me after linking a module. I had the same issue on Android just now and that fixed it (again). iOS or Android shouldn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ios, I tried to init a new react-native project, installed `react-navigation` and `react-native-gesture-handler`, linked them, then the error was fixed!

I think init a new project is the fastest way to fix the issue.